# What happens to a file/directory after you remove it with rm -rf but is still open in VS Code or anorhet app?

Tags: linux, macos, visual-studio-code, rm

This happens me a lot. I remove directory with `rm -rf` but see it is still open in an application such as VS Code.

My concern is that does it cause some folders to be copied for VS Code to be still operable on open files. If this is the case, do I need to find those duplicate copies and remove them as well, after closing the application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most operating systems there is a difference between the
file-name and the file-data.

The file-name is located in the partition's file-table and points
to the file-data on the disk.
Opening the file then in effect just fetched the pointer to the data.

The OS counts the number of connections to the file-data, and will
delete it when the number of references becomes zero.

After opening the file, there will two references to the data,
one from the file-table and one from the program.

If you then remove the file-name, then the number of references is
decreased by one. This still leaves the reference from the program
that opened the file.

When the program later closes the file (or terminates), the number
of references becomes zero, so the file-data is then finally
released to become free space.

In conclusion, you don't have to do anything - the OS does all the
necessary bookkeeping for you, so everything is automatic.

While the file is open in VS Code and if you removed the
file-name and then would like to go back and undo the delete,
you may from VS Code save the file back to its original name.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation and your time!

Answer (score 0):

Tha app just holds it in RAM. It won't find out until you try to save it.